# Text Based Game: Get item command not working

Tags: python, list, append

Firstly I'm still just learning python and new to stackoverflow so go easy on me.
I'm creating a text based game for one of my classes and I am trying to add an item inputted by the player and append it to their inventory. For some reason I cannot get it to append and that's where I'm stuck.

Here's my current program

```
# Displays instructions
def show_instructions():
    print('Welcome to the Alien Invasion game')
    print('Aliens have invaded your ship!!')
    print('Collect all 6 items in order to defeat them!\n')
    print('Movement: go [direction](North, South, East, or West)')
    print('Get item: get [item name]')
    print('_____________________________________________________')


# Rooms
rooms = {
    'Cockpit': {'West': 'Engine Control Room'},
    'Engine Control Room': {'East': 'Cockpit', 'North': 'Canteen', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Canteen': {'North': 'Sleeping Quarters', 'South': 'Engine Control Room', 'East': 'Med Bay',
                'West': 'Command Center', 'Item': 'Energy Bar'},
    'Command Center': {'East': 'Canteen', 'Boss': 'Aliens'},
    'Sleeping Quarters': {'South': 'Canteen', 'East': 'Storage', 'Item': 'Space Suit'},
    'Armory': {'South': 'Med Bay', 'Items': 'Ray Gun'},
    'Storage': {'West': 'Sleeping Quarters', 'Item': 'Space Helmet'},
    'Med Bay': {'North': 'Armory', 'West': 'Canteen', 'Item': 'Stim Pack'},
}

# List for players inventory
inventory = []

# Tracks current room
current_room = 'Cockpit'

# Calls function
show_instructions()

# Loop to keep game going
while True:
    # Prints Status
    print(f"You are in the {current_room}\nInventory: {inventory}\n")
    # Item Detection
    if 'Item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        nearby_item = rooms[current_room]['Item']

        if nearby_item not in inventory:
            print(f'There is a {nearby_item}')

    # Boss Detection
    if "Boss" in rooms[current_room].keys():
        # Lose Condition
        if len(inventory) < 6:
            print('ZAP ZAP ZAP\n YOU LOSE!!!')
            break
        # Win Condition
        else:
            print('CONGRATULATIONS!!\n YOU WIN!!')
            break

    # Player Input
    user_input = input('Enter your move: ')

    # Splitting Input
    next_move = user_input.split(' ')  # Splitting to check whether input is a direction or get item

    action = next_move[0].title()

    if len(next_move) > 1:
        item = next_move[1:]
        direction = next_move[1].title()

        item = ' '.join(item).title()

    # Movement
    if action == "Go":

        try:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
            print(f"You went {direction}.")
            print('_________________')

        except:
            print("You can't go that way.")

    # Get Items
    elif action == "Get":

        try:
            if item == rooms[current_room]["Item"]:

                if item not in inventory:

                    inventory.append[current_room]["Item"]
                    print(f"You got {item}")

                else:
                    print("Invalid Input")
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")
        except:
            print("Invalid Input")

    # Exit Game
    elif action == "Exit":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

I'm not getting any actual error the items just aren't appending to the inventory list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My If condition within a while loop doesn't break the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75982322/my-if-condition-within-a-while-loop-doesnt-break-the-loop)

Comment: Don't use a general `except` to catch all possible exceptions. You will loose important information about an error. Only catch expected exceptions in the smallest possible try-block.

Comment: `inventory.append[current_room]["Item"]` You need parentheses around the thing you're appending.  `inventory.append(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This is also my first response on StackOverflow, so bear with me...

But I think you made a simple mistake in your append function here:

```
            if item not in inventory:

                inventory.append[current_room]["Item"]
                print(f"You got {item}")
```

It should be:

```
            if item not in inventory:

                inventory.append(rooms[current_room]["Item"])
                print(f"You got {item}")
```

As you cannot access the current_room dictionary without first going to rooms.